# Pip Installation Problems EnvironmentError

Tags: pip

**I have no problems installing other dependencies but *djangorestframework_simplejwt* gives me the following error.**

`Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(54, 'Connection reset by peer'))': /packages/3d/d7/92c717da4e3474fef8a5415391170eba60be16a4e531c9027c38b2c329c8/djangorestframework_simplejwt-3.2.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl`

`Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='files.pythonhosted.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /packages/3d/d7/92c717da4e3474fef8a5415391170eba60be16a4e531c9027c38b2c329c8/djangorestframework_simplejwt-3.2.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (Caused by ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(54, 'Connection reset by peer')))`

**EDIT**

It seems to be a problem with my virtualenv. When I `deactivate` it then pip works fine.

**WORKAROUND**

So I found a workaround for the time being. I `deactivated` my env, then did `pip install djangorestframework-simplejwt`, then `source bin/activate` to activate my env. Then I would run `pip install djangorestframework-simplejwt`, it would use the cached version.

Comment: I think it is a problem with the djangorestframework_simplejwt lib.

Comment: So are you able to install `djangorestframework-simplejwt` when the env is not activated?

Comment: @hoefling Yes I was able to when the env was deactivated.

Comment: You've been here long enough to know not to edit the solution into your question. If you want to share the solution, please do so properly by writing an answer in the space provided below for that purpose. See [Can I answer my own question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) for more information.

Comment: @KenWhite It is not really an answer. I am still waiting for an answer.

Comment: The workaround isn't part of the problem. It's a temporary solution.

Comment: I'd first check whether the `pip` and `python` versions inside venv match the system ones (`pip -V` vs `path/to/venv/bin/pip -V` and `python -V` vs `path/to/venv/bin/python -V`) to make sure you have the identical setup, then check whether the pip config matches - do you have `$HOME/.pip/pip.conf`/`path/to/venv/pip.conf` files, do their contents match?